# How to read data from database in angularjs c#

Tags: c#, angularjs

Hi I have Brand table in DB has Code and Name. I am trying to get it brandlist using Angularjs.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
 app.controller("CateCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.ShowBrandList();

   //Show from DB
   $scope.ShowBrandList = function () {
var httpreq = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'Brand.aspx/GetBrandList',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'dataType': 'json'
    },
    data: {}
}
$http(httpreq).success(function (response) {
    $scope.brandList = response.d;
})
 };

});
```

In my Brand.aspx.cs

```
 [WebMethod]
    public List<Master_BrandBLL> GetBrandList()
    {
        return Master_BrandBLL.GetALLBrands();
    }
```

In Brand.aspx

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="CateCtrl">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    No
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Code
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Name
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="brand in brand.brandList">
                                <td>
                                    {{$index}}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{ brand.Code }}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{ brand.Name }}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

In my webservice working fine with jquery. But It can't show anything with angularjs.

Comment: `$scope.brandList = response.d;` why ".d" and use brandList in ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the BrandList through the controller. Your ng-repeat should be:

```
ng-repeat = "brand in CateCtrl.brandList"
```

Comment: Because my glasses suck. I could've sworn you were using controllerAs. You should be though. :) I can't recommend following the guidelines recommended here: github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1 strongly enough. – Mike Feltman 9 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="brand in brandList">
```